# How to make a window popup similar to command prompt in flex?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, command-prompt

I am new to eclipse and Java, and I am using flex as client side in my project.
What I need to do is to create a popup window similar to command prompt window, that popups on a button click.
I have created the button:

```
<mx:Button id="ping" label="Ping a Device" click="CallingWindow()">
```

CallingWindow() must make the window simlar to command prompt popup.
Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create a PopUp:

```
Alert.show("hello world!");
```

don't forget to import

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
```

To give it some style:

```
<mx:Style>
      Alert {
         borderColor: #666666;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         color: #999999;
      }
   </mx:Style>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: okay, but how can i apply a style to the alert? Let's say i made the backgroudcolor black so it will look like the command prompt, how can I apply this style to the alert?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? btw what flex vo are you using?